# UIView that expands with a gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uiviewanimation, expand

I'd need to make a subview expandable as long as the user taps a finger on it and drags it down, and collapsed again to its initial size when the user releases it (is that a Pan gesture?)

I've been looking for an example for this, with no success. Could somebody tell me which should be the best way to implement that?

Comment: You mean the view should expand when user slides finger down on the view?

Comment: What you're describing (tap and drag) is a pan gesture. Have a look at other panGestureRecognizers and the states (Began, Changed, Ended). You should essentially use the recognizer's scales and transform to alter the frame of the UIView you want to affect. And when you're in the Gesture Ended state, revert the frame of the view to what it originally was.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov yes, the idea is to allow the user to see more content within the view as he drags it down (until the content limit is reached), and then collapsed again when the user releases the finger

Comment: @AlanS do you know any good tutorial/example I could check?

Comment: @AppsDev I haven't personally used any but i'll link a tutorial at the end of the comment that looks decent in understanding the basics of panGesture, but it doesn't use the states, but does give a decent understanding. 

The second tutorial uses states slightly, but I prefer to use them to save any necessary values. You could particularly use the GestureEnded state to reset your frame.

https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/02/uipangesturerecognizer-tutorial-in.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial